# Why aren't my global variables seeming to change?

Tags: c++

I am a trying to create a very simplistic RPG and have defined several global variables at the top of my program. Within the function, mage, I have created an equation to calculate the damage of an ability using existing global variables whose values should have been updated according to the function. However, within the function, monsterFight, I call ability1 and every time it takes away nothing. I.e., it seems to take away a value of 0. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int XP;
int HP;
int LVL;
int DMG;

string ability1Name;
float ability1;

void mage() {
    HP = 10;
    DMG = 5;
    ability1Name = "Magic Bolt";
    ability1 = (DMG * 1.1) * (LVL * 1.25);
}

void warrior() {
    HP = 12;
    DMG = 4;
}

void paladin() {
    HP = 15;
    DMG = 3;
}

void monsterStart(string monsterName, int level, int health) {
    cout << "*************" << endl;
    cout << "Name: " << monsterName << endl;
    cout << "Level: " << level << endl;
    cout << "HP: " << health << endl;
    cout << "*************" << endl;
}

void monsterFight(int health) {
    while (true) {
        cout << "Select an ability: " << endl << "A. " << ability1Name << endl;
        char abilitySelect;
        cin >> abilitySelect;
        if (abilitySelect == 'A') {
            health - ability1;
            cout << "Monster's HP: " << health << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    int LVL = 1;

    cout << "Welcome to the RPG!" << endl;
    cout << "Please select a class: " << endl << "A. Mage\nB. Warrior\nC. Paladin" << endl;

    char SL1;

    cin >> SL1;

    if (SL1 == 'A') {
        mage();
        cout << "You chose Mage!" << endl;
    }
    else if (SL1 == 'B') {
        warrior();
        cout << "You chose Warrior!" << endl;
    }
    else if (SL1 == 'C') {
        paladin();
        cout << "You chose Paladin!" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Let us have a tutorial by you defeating a practice monster!" << endl;
    monsterStart("Dummy", 1, 10);
    monsterFight(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Pro Tip] Don't use global variables.  There are some cases where they are needed (global constants for instance) but otherwise they just make the code harder to understand and maintain, which is the opposite of what you want.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo: `health - ability1;` --> `health -= ability1;`

Comment: Many of the mistakes in the code being pointed out often are caught by the compiler and reported as warnings. Do not ignore warnings. Warnings are the first line of defense against logic errors. You can either understand and fix the problem when the compiler brings them up or fix them when your testing demonstrates that the program is not working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of main you are accidentally re-declaring LVL not assigning to your global. The global LVL is likely being initialized to 0 by the debugger making your damage calculation have a multiply by zero.

```
int LVL;
int main() {
    LVL = 1; //assigning to global
    int LVL = 1;//declaring a 'shadow' variable
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I see that now. Thank you! And if you don't mind answering, why aren't global variables seen as good coding practice? How should I go about that?

Comment: @AG77 *why aren't global variables seen as good coding practice?* -- You call a function.  Did it affect the global variable in some way?  Now try to maintain a program with that doubt in mind for several hundred or so function and function calls.

Comment: @AG77 It is also hard to improve the program to have two characters as both will have the same number of hit points.

Comment: I find this page to be a thorough explanation https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/why-global-variables-are-evil/

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily your usage of global variables, although as @NathanOliver pointed out, this is a bad practice.

You need to remove  `int` from `int LVL = 1;` in `main()`. Your global value remains 0 in the original code, while you create a new locally scoped `LVL` that is 1. However, your functions will only see the global `LVL`, not the local one.

Comment: An expression like `int * float` will be of type `float` already, so the cast you're suggesting doesn't actually do anything. The issue is what it's being assigned into. Does this example show what I'm trying to say? https://ideone.com/5tTl5R

Comment: @scohe001 Ah, after reading [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) I get it now. I was under the impression that the `int` would cause truncation before it was even assigned to the `float`. But now with that and your example I see that it implicitly converts the `int` to a `float` during arithmetic operations. The only issue is using the `=` operand when the left is an `int`, and the right evaluates to a `float`, which isn't the case here. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

You are re-declaring `LVL` in your main function, thus in your `mage` function the global `LVL` variable is 0.  Remove the `int` from the line

```
int LVL = 1;
```

so it becomes

```
LVL = 1;
```

so to not re-declare a local version of the variable.